# why does the if statement only work for "i"?

Tags: python-3.x

My job is to take the vowels out of strings inputted into the program. I tried to use if statements for each vowel within a for loop, however, the if statements only work for some vowels. (y not included)

```
def disemvowel(string):
    for i in string:
        char = i.lower()
        rplce = string.replace(char, "")
        if char == "a":
            return rplce
        elif char == "e":
            return rplce
        elif char == "i":
            return rplce
        elif char == "o":
            return rplce
        elif char == "u":
            return rplce
```

I expect for it to replace the vowels in the if statements with an empty string, however, it only works with "i" for some reason.
expected output: "Ths wbst s fr lsrs LL!"
actual output: "Ths webste s for losers LOL!"
input: "This website is for losers LOL!"

Comment: why are you returning inside for loop?only return when you are done iterating the string

Answer (score 1):

You are going in the right direction by using if statements, but when you put a return, it exits out of that function. What you are doing is a pre mature return that causes you to get a half processed string.

Try looking into the working of `continue`

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
res = ""
for letter in word:
    if letter in vowels:
        continue
    res += letter
return res
```